# Programatically adding a dynamic number of spaces to a string

Tags: c#, treeview

I've got a treeview control, which I want to look like this:

[image]

Just by messing around with css and a text string, I'm actually pretty close.  I just need some help getting over the line.

Here is the code I'm using to generate the treeview:

```
    void FillTree_Parent()
    {  // fills the parent view of the Tree Action items
        //int RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRole.SelectedValue);
        using (SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PBRConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ACCT_GRP], [ACCT_GRP_PK], [ACTIVE_FLG], [LOAD_BY], [LOAD_TIMESTAMP] FROM [ACCT_GRP_LIST] ORDER BY [ACCT_GRP] ASC", con4);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                DataSet PrSet = new DataSet();

                da.Fill(PrSet, "ACCT_GRP");
                TreeViewAccts.Nodes.Clear();
                foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dr["LOAD_TIMESTAMP"].ToString());
                    string formatted = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();
                // Here is our focus
                    tnParent.Text = dr["ACCT_GRP"].ToString().Replace("'", "''") + 
                    " ········· " + "Active:" + dr["ACTIVE_FLG"].ToString() + 
                    " ········· " + "Loaded On:" + formatted + "";
                //
                    tnParent.Value = dr["ACCT_GRP_PK"].ToString();
                    tnParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;
                    tnParent.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
                    TreeViewAccts.Nodes.Add(tnParent);
                    FillTree_Child(tnParent, tnParent.Value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ae)
            {
                Response.Write(ae.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

In that block marked "// Here is our focus", what I need to do is figure out how to get that first set of " ········· " to generate a dynamic number of spaces based on the fact that dr["ACCT_GRP"] can have as many as 75 characters.  So, I need to determine the length of dr["ACCT_GRP"], subtract that from 75 and then generate that many spaces.

Can anyone help me with this logic?  Also, as a bonus question, if anyone could tell me how to use spaces instead of "·"'s I'd appreciate it; whenever I just hit the spacebar a bunch of times and enclose it in quotes, it acts like those spaces don't even exist.

Comment: [Monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Courier.  But blank spaces (using the spacebar) are still ignored when building the string for some reason.

Comment: Looks like I can use "&nbsp;" to create a space, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

Comment: You could always use the tab character: "&#9;".  Edit: Forgot to mention, but you have to place it between <pre></pre> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        int len = dr["ACCT_GRP"].Length;
        int paddingLength = 75 - len;
        string padding = new string('.', paddingLength);
```

I get it from your question that you are viewing this in a browser (you mentioned CSS). HTML spec tells the browser to collapse all consecutive whitespace into a single space. You can use the "non-breaking space" character instead. It may be written as "&nbs p;" in HTML (minus the space between s and p) or using its Unicode representation 00 A0. So your c# code becomes:

```
        int len = dr["ACCT_GRP"].Length;
        int paddingLength = 75 - len;
        string padding = new string('\u00A0', paddingLength);
```

Comment: So simple, yet it eluded me.  Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, Johny. Thanks for fixing the formatting. SO was messing it up.